# Angular 2 not showing images without restarting

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular2-template

I'm uploading an image using angular2 and nodejs, when node uploads file in assets folder, I try to show it using angular and get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/assets/img/3.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

But when my angular server restarts the image is there.

What can I do to show an image without restarting?

Comment: If you get a 404 with the proper URL, then the problem is not in angular, but in the server side

Comment: src="../../../assets/img/{{blog.image}}"  where blog.image is the name of image

Comment: i try but not working on that way, my new uploaded image visible in assets only when I restart angular-cli

Comment: @AnushChakhoyan my filing you are uploading images when angular app is running with `ng serve`, is it?

Comment: <div class="row" *ngIf="!newPost">
  <div class="product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let blog of blogPosts">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="head">{{blog.name}}</div>
      <img src="../../../assets/img/{{blog.image}}" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <p><strong>Brand: </strong>{{blog.brand}}</p>
        <p><strong>Country: </strong>{{blog.country}}</p>
        <p><strong>Price: </strong>{{blog.price}}</p>      </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: all I have is this

Comment: yes you are right @Kuncevic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you reply to my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399704/angular-2-not-showing-images-without-restarting#comment79760130_46399704) - you are using `ng serve`.

The thing is, when you are running `ng serve` that triggered in memory `webpack dev server` - not a thing you want to run on your server, that is for dev only. This way, until you restarted `ng serve`, you wont get any changes happend in your `assets` folder as it is [default folder for your `static assets` configured in `.angular-cli.json`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration):

> You use the assets array in .angular-cli.json to list files or folders
>   you want to copy as-is when building your project.

So `assets` folder is not the best place to store any dynamic content.

Comment: @AnushChakhoyan I do not know any details about your uploading process but I guessing that it is implemented as an separate API. So you have to change the output folder for that(should be a folder outside the anuglar app, write images to the folder that belongs to your server side) then once image is uploaded you have to request that image from your server in your angular app.

Comment: @Kuncevic I am also struggling with this. Before I was uploading files to assets/upload folder but from this answer I have uploaded image to public/uploads folder. But I don't know how to access that image from angular. Can you tell me how to access that image?